# Duplicating new row of php table with populated dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a new row of php table with two populated dropdown lists. There are three columns in one row, two of them have populated dropdown lists which if I choose one data from one, the other dropdown list will be populated automatically according to what I had chosen.

I had tried to create a new row, but the problem is whenever I chose from first the dropdown list on any rows, only the second dropdown list in the first row of the table is changing. I can't get each row  of the second dropdown list to work like when I choose from the first dropdown list, the second dropdown on the same row list gets populated.

Here is the code:

addrecipe.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(str) {
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("productn").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("productn").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","pname.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myCreateFunction() {
var i = 10;
var ii = 10;
var iii = 10;
if (i <= 20){
    i++;
    ii++;
    iii++;
   var table = document.getElementById("table");
   var row = table.insertRow(11);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

   cell1.innerHTML = 
    '<select name="product_'+i+'" id="product" onchange="show(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodcat");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['catID'].'">'.$row['prodCat'].'</option>'; }
    ?>  
    </select>';

  cell2.innerHTML = 
   '<select name="productn_'+ii+'" id="productn">   
   <option value="">Select...</option>   
   <?php $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");  
   while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))   {
   echo '<option value="'.$row1['IngID'].'">'.$row1['IngName'].'</option>'; }   
   ?>
   </select>';

  cell3.innerHTML = '<input class="style" type="text" name="qty_'+iii+'" id="qty">';
  }
  }

 </script>

 <tr>
                <td>
                <select name="product_1[]" id="product" onchange="show(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
                <?php 
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodcat");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['catID'].'">'.$row['prodCat'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <select name="productn_1[]" id="productn">
                <option value="">Select...</option><?php
                $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
                {
                echo '<option value="'.$row1['IngID'].'">'.$row1['IngName'].'</option>';
                }?>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input class="style" type="text" name="qty_1[]" id="qty">
                </td>
</tr>
```

pname.php

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("cannot select DB");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE catID='$q'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['IngID'].'">'.$row['IngName'].'</option>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first set the dynamic id for all the drop downs for exammple

```
 function myCreateFunction() {
    var i = 10;
    if (i <= 20){
        i++;

       var table = document.getElementById("table");
       var row = table.insertRow(11);
       var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
       var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
       var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

    cell1.innerHTML = '<select name="productCategory_'+i+'" id="productCategory_'+i+'" onchange="setProducts(this.value,this.id)">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <?php $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prodcat");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['catID'].'">'.$row['prodCat'].'</option>'; }
        ?>  
       </select>';
       cell2.innerHTML = '<select name="productn_'+i+'" id="productn_'+i+'`enter code here`">   
       <option value="">Select...</option>   
       <?php $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");  
       while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))   {
       echo '<option value="'.$row1['IngID'].'">'.$row1['IngName'].'</option>'; }   
       ?>
       </select>'; 
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input class="style" type="text" name="qty_'+iii+'" id="qty_'+iii+'">';
  }
  }

function setProducts(value,id){ id = id.split("_")[1];
    // Here Assign Some Value by using this id
    // document.getElementById('productn_'+i) to get partiicular row dropdown

}
`
```

here you should name the select boxes with different id's ,so by we can call particular row easily..